# How do you solve $x^{-1} < 2-x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've tried to solve this inequality to no avail.

These are the steps I've tried:

$$ x^{-1} < 2 - x$$

$$ \frac1x < 2 - x$$

$$ \frac1x - 2 + x < 0$$

$$ \frac{1 - 2x + x^2}x < 0$$

$$ \frac{(x-1)^2}x < 0$$

After this, I'm not sure how to continue.

I've tried:

> (x - 1)^2 < 0x

> (x - 1) < √0

> x < 1

Which should give me a solution (-infinity, 1), but if I graph the inequality it is clearly (-infinity, 0).

I think my first mistake it's canceling that x with the 0, but I'm not sure.

I've tried different sites, like WolframAlpha, but they only give me the alternate form "(x-1)^2 / x < 0" or the solution "x < 0", but I have no clue how to get there.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You made multiple mistakes. 1. when multiplying through by $x$, you forgot to consider the sign of $x$; if it is negative it changes the inequality, so you would need to consider two cases ($x$ cannot be zero, you know that... do you see why?) 2. You mistakenly simplify $\sqrt{(x-1)^2}$ to $x-1$, but that's wrong. In general, $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$, so you would get $|x-1|\lt 0$... which is always false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. You already found $$\frac{(x-1)^2}x<0$$
Notice that $(x-1)^2$ is always positive, except for $x=1$, when it is $0$. So a positive number divided by $x$ is negative. Then $x$ is ....

Also note that if you multiply an inequality on both sides with a negative number ($x$ can be negative as well), then the sign of the inequality changes. $<$ will become $>$.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Now I see that I should always try to reason out an answer before trying to multiply or divide both sides of an inequality. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer, a real number squared will always be positive. Instead, if you keep the x instead of multiplying to both sides of $\frac{(x-1)^2}{x}<0$, then, the answer will be solvable if x is a negative number. So, this equation is correct when x<0.

Comment: Yeah, I completely missed that. The only way I can have a negative number is if one of the factors is negative, and that can't happen in the numerator, so the denominator has to be less than 0. Now I feel a little bit dumb haha.  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

> $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{x} < 2-x.$

Alternative approach.

Clearly, $x = 0$ is outlawed.

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~x > 0}$
Because $x > 0$, you have that 
$1 < 2x - x^2 \implies (x-1)^2 = x^2 - 2x + 1 < 0.$ 
Contradiction.

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~x < 0}$
Because $x < 0$, you have that 
$1 > 2x - x^2 \implies (x-1)^2 = x^2 - 2x + 1 > 0.$ 
At this point, it looks like $x$ can be any negative number. 
However, rather than verify that the inference was bidirectional, it is easier to work backwards.

Assume $x < 0.$ 
Then $x \neq 1 \implies (x - 1)^2 = x^2 - 2x + 1 > 0 \implies 1 > 2x - x^2.$ 
Then, because $x < 0$, one infers that 
$\frac{1}{x} < 2 - x.$

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve the inequality geometrically.  The curve for $ \ y \ = \ \frac{1}{x} \ $ is a "rectangular" hyperbola with one "branch" in the first quadrant $ \ ( x > 0 \ , \ y > 0 ) \ $ and the other in the third quadrant $ \ ( x < 0 \ , \ y  < 0 ) \ \ . $  The line $ \ y \ =  \ 2 - x \ $ has the intercepts $ \ (0 \ , \ 2) \ $ and $ \ (2 \ , \ 0) \ $ and does not pass through the third quadrant at all.  So the inequality $ \ \frac{1}{x} \ < \ 2 - x \ \ $ is solved by the branch of the hyperbola that lies *completely* "below" the line, which is the portion in the third quadrant.  So the solution interval is $ \ x \ < \ 0 \ \ . $

[Were the inequality   $ \ \frac{1}{x} \ \le \ 2 - x \ \ $ -- which would be a sneaky problem -- we would also have to include the intersection of the two curves at $ \ ( 1 \ , \ 1) \ \ , $ making that solution $ \ x \ < \ 0 \ \ , \ \ x \ = \ 1 \ \ . \ ] $